# put vb.net nested session value in a javascript variable

Tags: vb.net, session-variables

I have a vb.net aspx page that i need to assign a session variable inside of javascript

if i do the following

```
var baz ="<%=Session("User")%>";
alert(baz);
```

the alert i receive is the class name

```
 "TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser"
```

i need a nested value of this session , and have no idea how to do this in vb

i do however know how to do this in C# / generic http handler

```
 ...
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    IAdvanceUser user = context.Session["User"] as IAdvanceUser;
 ... 
    var ID = user.EntityID
```

and of course in php, RoR , ColdFusion, ect

I have tried this but it failed miserably

```
var baz ="<%=Session("User").("EntityId")%>";
alert(baz);
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: use `CType(fromObjectHere, toObjectHere)`

```
var baz ="<%= CType(Session("User"), AdvanceUser).EntityID %>";
```

**Update**

You might need to type the full name `TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser` or import the namespace

```
<%= CType(Session("User"), TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser).EntityID %>
```

Comment: got error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @worthycaesar That means the object in session is not IAdvanceUser. From your question it should be `AdvanceUser`. Check my update

Comment: Type 'AdvanceUser' is not defined, guarantee its close though

Comment: You might need to type the full name `TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser` or import the namespace

Comment: `<%= CType(Session("User"), TheName.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser).EntityID %>`

Comment: that's perfect, and I understand now how this works, make an answer and i'll upvote/accept...thanks again for your help